# VS2005 .net 2.0 c# : Best way to create xml file

Tags: c#, xml

What is the best way to create xml file in .net 2.0 in terms of nodes etc. I dont think I could use LINQ. Any code sample or article would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You best bet is to use the [XmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx) class.

Here's a pretty basic example:

```
var writer = new XmlTextWriter("Foo.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
writer.WriteStartDocument();
writer.WriteStartElement("Foo");
writer.WriteAttributeString("hello", "world"); 
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndDocument();
writer.Close();
```

This will give you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Foo hello="world" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code snippet that works:

```
XmlTextWriter myXW  = new XmlTextWriter(@"C:\NewXmlFile.xml", Encoding.UTF8)
myXW.WriteStartDocument();
myXW.WriteStartElement("Customers");
string strConn = myConnectionString;
OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
myConn.Open();
OleDbCommand myCMD = new OleDbCommand("select * from customers", myConn);
OleDbDataReader myRdr = myCMD.ExecuteReader();
while (myRdr.Read())
{
    myXW.WriteStartElement("Customer");
    myXW.WriteAttributeString("id", myRdr.GetString(0));
    myXW.WriteElementString("companyname", myRdr.GetString(1));
    myXW.WriteElementString("contactname", myRdr.GetString(2));
    myXW.WriteElementString("contactname", myRdr.GetString(3));
    myXW.WriteElementString("address", myRdr.GetString(4));
    myXW.WriteElementString("city", myRdr.GetString(5));
    myXW.WriteElementString("country", myRdr.GetString(8));
    myXW.WriteElementString("phone", myRdr.GetString(9));
    myXW.WriteElementString("fax", myRdr.GetString(10));
    myXW.WriteEndElement();
}
myXW.WriteEndElement();
myXW.WriteEndDocument();
myXW.Flush();
myXW.Close();
```

Comment: Like the example...but pull out the un-necessary code to make it more readable.

Comment: @Justin Neissner: You mean the ADO stuff?  You think that adds unnecessary noise? I was hoping it would add context.  I'm open to feedback.